# ExpandableListView with two TextViews per Item

Tags: android, listview, textview, expandablelistview

Is it possible to put more than one TextView in the items of a ExpandableListView?
I've tried this, and not working, the second TV is not shown:

group_item.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/row_name"
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     android:textSize="18dp"
     android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:textStyle="normal"
     android:layout_width="320dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/row_desc"
    android:text="Some text here"
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     android:textSize="18dp"
     android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:textStyle="normal"
     android:layout_width="320dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: You can put whatever you want as a ListView item, how are you setting the adapter? What's your full group_item.xml?

Comment: Did you add it to your adapter call?  Are you using arrays or cursors?  Need more info.  Edit the question and post at least you call for the ExpandableListView adapter and the adapter itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what's backing your listview, so I'll show an example with cursors (assuming a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter).

```
mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(
    mGroupsCursor,                                  // cursor supplying group data
    getActivity(),                                  // context
    R.layout.group_item,                            // Group row layout
    R.layout.child_item,                            // Child row layout
    new String[] { "column1", "column2" },          // Cursor columns from group cursorto be mapped to group view
    new int[] { R.id.row_name, R.id.row_desc },     // View ids to receive group column data
    new String[] { "child1", "child2"},             // Cursor columns from child cursor to be mapped to child view
    new int[] { R.id.child1, R.id.child2            // View ids to receive child column data
});    
lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);                        // Set your adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. But you will have to do your own binding. Therefor make a custom adapter and overwrite the bindGroupView or bindChildView method.

-edit-

I'm sorry, I was a bit confused with the question. If all you want to do is fill two textviews then you do not have to overwrite the bindgroupview or bindchildview methods. That's only if you need to do more complex binding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible an example for you I added to github.

I am working on frozen columns exp in this project. ignore them. In the adapter you will see multiple columns

https://github.com/huseyinDaVinci/Android/tree/master/ExpandableListView